# error: expected expression before 'matriz'

Tags: c, array

El programa debería leer una matriz desde teclado pero tira este error

> error: expected expression before 'matriz'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 3
typedef int matriz[TAM][TAM];

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<TAM; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<TAM; j++)
        {
            printf("Ingrese el elemento [%d,%d] ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void Mostrar (matriz M)  
{
    int i,j ;    
    for (i=0; i<TAM; i++) 
        for (j=0; j<TAM; j++)
            printf("%d",M[i][j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un poco de cacao. Pretendes que `matriz` se comporte como variable y como tipo a la vez y eso no es posible:

```
scanf("%d",&matriz[i][j]); // <<--- variable

void Mostrar (matriz M)  // <<--- tipo
```

Para esta respuesta vamos a asumir que tu intención es que `matriz` sea un tipo.

`typedef` sirve para definir un alias y su sintaxis es:

```
typedef [alias] [tipo];
```

En tu caso el programa entiende que `int` es un alias y `matriz[TAM][TAM]` es el tipo... y claro, eso de `matriz` al compilador le suena a chino porque no es un tipo válido.

El código debería quedar más bien así:

```
typedef matriz int[TAM][TAM];
```

Ahora hay que corregir la función `main` ya que ahora mismo está asumiendo que `matriz` es una variable... cuando realmente es un tipo. Lo primero que hay que hacer es declarar una variable:

```
int main()
{
    matriz M;

    for(int i=0; i<TAM; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<TAM; j++)
        {
            printf("Ingrese el elemento [%d,%d] ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&M[i][j]);
        }
    }

    Mostrar(M); // <<--- Esto te falta
}
```

Y listo, con estos cambios el programa ya debería compilar sin problemas.